# Black screen on starting app

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing

I have noticed that on android versions 6.0+,when someone starting app after login screen and submiting info,black screen appear and you have to wait 3-15 sec depending on devices.

I heard that it could be for heavy loadings,but this app is nothing special it just load listview with few images after login (i had 3 images while tested) so im not sure is it really that heavy plus it only happen on newer versions of android so im not sure what to do.

I can provide whole code or some snippet.

EDIT: I tried with various image sizes (full loaded with big images,and only 1 small image) and it have no effect at all.

Anyone???

Comment: try doing one thing, try building your debug apk from Build -> Build APKs, and install that apk to your device and check. The apk can be found in app -> build -> outputs -> apk -> debug

Comment: What is supposed to happen?I already have my app installed.

Comment: your issue was supposed to get resolved. seems that it didn't :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your  manifest file .

In your Activity tag add this theme.

*android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"*

And then you need to extend your respective activity from Activity class.

It will work for sure

Comment: I have added android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent", also extending Activity instead of AppCompatActivity,and now app looks like its 2012...

Answer (score 0):

For those who face this error in future

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="MainTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```